# Concourse .yml file aws credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, concourse

I am new to concourse.

We use concourse. I have deployPipeline.yml file and I can see task has params as below.

```
aws_access_key_id: ((accountaws.key))
aws_secret_access_key: ((accountaws.secret))
```

Where these values accountaws.key and accountaws.secret are coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `vars` section of the [Concourse pipeline documentation](https://concourse-ci.org/setting-pipelines.html). You would need to pass the value for those vars when you run the `fly set-pipeline` command. The documentation I linked shows the different methods of doing that.

You would get the AWS API Key ID and Secret Key by creating an AWS IAM account with the appropriate permissions needed for this Concourse job, and downloading the API credentials for that account.